# PD control with gravity compensation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, robotics

Given the robot dynamics of the form
$$M(\theta)\ddot{\theta}+C(\theta, \dot{\theta})\dot{\theta}+G(\theta)=u$$
where the notations have the standard meaning ($M$ is the inertia matrix, $C$ is Coriolis-centrifugal matrix, and $G$ is the gravity). Let the desired configuration of the robot be $\theta_d$. To track this desired configuration, we apply the following control law with a gravity compensation:
$$u=-K_p(\theta-\theta_d)-K_d\dot{\theta}+G(\theta)$$
The gain matrices $K_p, K_d$ can be assumed to be diagonal with the diagonal elements being $k_p, k_d$ respectively.

Now I need to show **1. Stability**, **2. Asymptotic Stability**, **3. Exponential Stability**. Where the definitions of the quantities of the above are as follows:
Let $V$ be a non-negative function with derivative ¤ defined along the trajectories/solution of the system.

**Stability**: If $V$ is locally pdf(positive definite) and $\dot{V} \leq 0$ locally, then equilibrium point $x^* = 0$ is locally stable.

**Asymptotic stability**: $V$ is locally pdf and locally decresant, $-\dot{V}$ locally pdf, then $x^*=0$ is locally asymptotically stable. $V$ is pdf and radially unbounded and decrescant, $-\dot{V}$ is pdf, then $x^*=0$ is globally asymptotically stable.

**Exponential stability:**: $x^*=0$ is exponentially stable if there exists a $V$, that satifies the following:
$$\alpha_1||x||^2 \leq V(x) \leq \alpha_2||x||^2$$
$$\dot{V}\leq -\alpha_3 ||x||^2$$

I am not sure how to proceed with the given problem. Any help/relevant resource is helpful.

Comment: Local or global results?

Comment: @KBS judging by the question, I would guess everything needs to be shown locally.

Comment: Then, just linearize the dynamics about the equilibrium point and analyze its stability. DO you have any assumptions on $M$ and $C$? Like sign, bounds, etc.

Comment: @KBS no, there are no particular restrictions on $M,C$ as such.